# How to find out if CheckBox was clicked on DataGrid.GotFocus()

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to implement a single-click behavior for setting CheckBoxes inside a DataGrid Column. This works, but I would like to only toggle the IsChecked Property, when the cursor is above a Checkbox. Currently I switch whenever the DataGridCell gets focus.

I could not find a way to determine if the mouse cursor is above a Checkbox...

```
private void dataGridCell_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell focusedCell = e.OriginalSource as DataGridCell;
    if (focusedCell != null)
    {
        DataGrid grd = (DataGrid)sender;
        grd.BeginEdit(e);

        Control editControl = focusedCell.Descendants<Control>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (editControl != null)
        {
            CheckBox checkBox = editControl as CheckBox;
            if (checkBox != null)
            {
                if (checkBox.IsEnabled)
                {
                    checkBox.Focus();
                    checkBox.SetCurrentValue(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, !checkBox.IsChecked);

                    var bindingExpression = checkBox.GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);
                    if (bindingExpression != null)
                    {
                        bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
                dataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => editControl.Focus()), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Best regards
Gope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for:

```
bool isMouseOver = checkBox.InputHitTest(Mouse.GetPosition((IInputElement) checkBox)) != null;
```

this will return null, when the mouse is not over the CheckBox, simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not the most elegant way but this works:

Replace the original template of the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
          <CheckBox IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
```

In your event-handler:

```
public void dataGridCell_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.OriginalSource is CheckBox)
  {
    // checkbox was clicked
  }
  else if (e.OriginalSource is DataGridCell)
  {
    // somwhere outside the checkbox was clicked
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Although I don't understand why this should work, I didn't test and can't deny that it may work. :) As the column is created in CodeBehind, it would need a little more effort than your sample showed. I would have tried, if I hadn't just found what I was looking for. Thanks again!